# C Make copy of data from struct pointer

Tags: c, struct

I have small problem with creating a copy of data.

In C I have function

```
struct data* copy_and_change(const struct data* input_data)
```

`struct data` contains one pointer to `struct header` and some integers

`struct header` is struct which contains information about user (chars, ints...)

```
struct data{
    struct header* info;  
    int salary;
};
```

So parameter is `const struct pointer` to data in memory.

My function should grab data from parameter and create copy of that data, rearrange it and return a pointer to new data (copied data)

Rearranging and doing stuff with data is no problem. problem is to make a copy of data

My question: what I should use to make copy of data?

I was trying to use `memcpy()`.
gcc gives error `argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘memcpy’ call is the same expression as the destination; did you mean to dereference it?`
- probably beacuse of param is const

Comment: `I was trying to use memcpy`, and what happened?

Comment: "I was trying to use memcpy()."   ---> post that code.  Even better: [mcve].

Comment: before memcpy, do you allocate a suitable memory block with malloc ?

Comment: If it's okay to do a shallow copy, then using `memcpy` (or just plain assignment) should work fine. Assuming that you have created a suitable instance of the `data` structure for the destination of the copying.

Comment: You don't even need to use `memcpy`, you can just assign one structure to another and C will copy the entire structure.  But it will be a *shallow copy*, so if you need a deep copy, you will need to copy that data as well, and of course, you will need to allocate space for everything copied.

Comment: well, the result of memcpy was a shallow copy of data, because i have stored string in struct header* info. So, i need to make a deep copy,

Comment: So you want to create a deep copy of the data? So what is a `struct header`? Is there a `header_copy` function that can copy a header? `gcc gives error argument` please post the code that you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to create  copy of input_data. Then why don't you create local variable put the data in it.I don't understand need of memcpy

Try this

```
struct  data *copy=malloc(sizeof(struct data));
*copy=*input_data;
 //your rearranging code here
 return copy;
```

Comment: I presume from the function signature that the OP needs to return a pointer to a new, dynamically-allocated structure. In that case, the local variable part does not seem relevant, but the structure assignment angle is still a good observation.  I would be inclined to agree that the best way to copy the full contents of a structure to another structure of the same type is by assignment, except in one or two special cases that do not appear to apply here.

Comment: I fixed it. Now i mallocate the correct size of struct.  i badly explained it to you. NOW: I created new struct result, then mallocate size(calculated using input_data), then used assgiment to copydata. Now when i do printf %p }address|, they are different.  To be 100% sure that it is correct, i updated some data and saved them to file. Thak you guys, sorry for my bad english

Comment: @Jimmyguitaro check my answer is that what you mean?